# graph theory, relation between chromatic index and maximum matching

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

consider the following algorithm to find a minimum edge coloring in a graph G=(V,E)

```
let k = 0
while E has edges:
 k = k+1
 Let M be a maximum matching in G=(V,E)
 For every e in M, mark e with color k
 E = E - M
```

Could you find a proof (counter example?) that for some graph G it does not find G's chromatic index? It has to exists otherwise edge coloring would be in P since there is a polynomial time algorithm to find a maximum matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm can fail if you start with the five vertex graph built from a square with an additional central point connected to each vertex of the square (such graphs are sometimes called *wheels*, although this particular wheel won't work so well on a wheelbarrow).  If the first matching avoids the central point, the algorithm will return at best an edge five coloring, whereas the graph itself is edge four colorable.

Comment: I suppose a simpler example would be a path on five vertices (four edges).  If the first matching picks the outermost pair of edges, the algorithm will guess chromatic index three instead of the correct answer of two.

Comment: thats a good example. therefore there's no limit on how bad this approximation is compared to the chromatic index? for example a center vertex joining togheter _n_ P5's could be n colors apart from the optimum coloring.